# Add/insert a new column after a specific column and apply formula in that new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying find or lookup a specific column then add or insert a new column named "Response Time" after that column.

Then in newly added column apply a formula that subtracts two columns namely "Find Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual" and "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd" in the newly added column named "Response Time".

```vb
Sub addt()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim wsh As Worksheets
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range
    
    Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long, col As Long
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut")
        'Find Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual
        'Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd
                  
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut")
        
            For Each cl In Range("1:1")
                If cl = "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd" Then
                    cl.EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlRight
                End If
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Response Time"
            Next cl
                
            ' Copy Header Fromat
            .Cells(1, cl).Copy
            .Cells(1, cl + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut")
        
                col1 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual", _
                  After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                    
                col2 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd", _
                  After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                
                ' Apply Formula to "Response Time" column range
                For i = 2 To cl
                    .Cells(i, cl + 1).Formula = .Cells(i, col2) - .Cells(i, col1)
                    .Cells(i, cl + 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
                Next i
                    
            End With
             
        End With
        
    End With
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: But what's wrong with your code? Do you receive an error?  Does it something else then you need? In principle, your code must check if `col1` and `col2` have been found and the formula should be written once for all the range, but you must determine the last row in the column you are using as reference to insert the new one. Anyhow, `For i = 2 To cl` does not make sens, since `cl` has been declared as a `Range`...

Comment: You need to put your `cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Response Time"` **inside** the If statement otherwise it does it on every loop. You also need to offset 1 column from `cl` when inserting if you want to insert the column after it, not before it. You also should then `Exit For` after you add `Response Time` to stop the loop continuing (saves time since your looping through everything).

Comment: I should add the reason for the error is because its applying to every column (as it's not in the if statement), therefore when you get to the last column in Excel you're trying to offset to the right and it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next updated code, please:

```
Sub addt()
 Dim lastR As Long, cl As Range, col1 As Long

    'Find Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual
    'Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut")
        For Each cl In .Range("1:1")
            If cl.Value = "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd" Then               
                cl.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight
                cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Response Time"
                cl.Copy
                cl.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Exit For ' exit the loop after finding the column
            End If
        Next cl
             
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutPut")
            col1 = .cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual", _
                        After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
            If col1 = 0 Then MsgBox "The column header could not be found...": Exit Sub

            lastR = .cells(rows.count, cl.Column).End(xlUp).row 'last row 
            'put formula (at once):
            .With .Range(cl.Offset(1, 1), .cells(lastR, cl.Offset(1, 1).Column))
                .Formula = "=" & cl.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & "-" & .cells(2, col1).Address(0, 0)
                .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            End With
         End With
         .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
      End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225128/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-macro-that-adds-inserts-a-new-column-after).